# Comparing 1 column of non-unique values to another column of non-unique values

Tags: sql

Not sure how to ask it properly so I'll try to visualize it. I have 2 columns lets say one is names and the names repeat( A couple Johns a few Lukes etc). The other column is pretty much languages but only a few(French, spanish, english, etc). Basically, each person can have multiple languages.

Im trying to find out if given a name, could I determine which other people are associated with all of the languages the original person is. So example being Mark knows French and Spanish. Using that, I would try and figure out who else knows French and Spanish. So if Jeremy knows French, Spanish, and German, he would show up in the results.

Any ideas?

So far I have

```
accept nameIn prompt 'Search for:'
select name from sc16temp intersect (select lang from sc16temp where name='&nameIn');
```

Comment: Can you precise the SQL flavour ?

Comment: its within Oracle so SQL Plus, but I would rather keep it as basic as possible so I would rather not any PL SQL

Comment: Do you have anything that uniquely identifies each user?  This can be done but the results would be useless without it.

Comment: And can you show us the schemas for the relevant tables?

Comment: "anything that uniquely identifies each user"
Their name. The name can be considered to be unique to one person but it appears multiple times, once for each language they know.
"can you show us the schemas for the relevant tables?"
http://i.imgur.com/Hchsb.png
thats all there is to it. Thats just a quick example of names and languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) with a reminder.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a02b4/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  Name varchar(10),
  Lang varchar(10),
  primary key (Name, Lang)
);

insert into YourTable values('John', 'English');
insert into YourTable values('John', 'French');
insert into YourTable values('John', 'Spanish');
insert into YourTable values('John', 'Swedish');

insert into YourTable values('Mark', 'English');
insert into YourTable values('Mark', 'French');
insert into YourTable values('Mark', 'Spanish');

insert into YourTable values('Peter', 'English');
insert into YourTable values('Peter', 'French');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select T1.Name
from YourTable T1
  inner join YourTable T2
    on T1.Lang = T2.Lang
where T2.Name = 'Mark'
group by T1.Name
having count(T1.Lang) = (select count(Lang) 
                         from YourTable 
                         where Name = 'Mark')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a02b4/11/0)**:

```
| NAME |
--------
| John |
| Mark |
```

Comment: yup that did it. Thanks! now to just ponder it and figure out how